# Creating webhook-notifications in testing environment

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm currently trying to create a test webhook-notification as it's shown in the documentation:

```java
HashMap<String, String> sampleNotification = gateway.webhookTesting().sampleNotification(
    WebhookNotification.Kind.SUBSCRIPTION_WENT_PAST_DUE, "my_id"
);

WebhookNotification webhookNotification = gateway.webhookNotification().parse(
    sampleNotification.get("bt_signature"),
    sampleNotification.get("bt_payload")
);

webhookNotification.getSubscription().getId();
// "my_id"
```

First off I don't know what `my_id` actually should be. Is it supposed to be a plan ID? Or should it be a `Subscription` ID?

I've tested all of it. I've set it to an existing billing plan in my vault and I also tried to create a `Customer` down to an actual `Subscription` like this:

```java
public class WebhookChargedSuccessfullyLocal {

    private final static BraintreeGateway BT;

    static {
        String btConfig = "C:\\workspaces\\mz\\mz-server\\mz-web-server\\src\\main\\assembly\\dev\\braintree.properties";
        Braintree.initialize(btConfig);
        BT = Braintree.instance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebhookChargedSuccessfullyLocal webhookChargedSuccessfullyLocal = new WebhookChargedSuccessfullyLocal();
        webhookChargedSuccessfullyLocal.post();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void post() {

        CustomerRequest customerRequest = new CustomerRequest()
                .firstName("Testuser")
                .lastName("Tester");

        Result<Customer> createUserResult = BT.customer().create(customerRequest);

        if(createUserResult.isSuccess() == false) {
            System.err.println("Could not create customer");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Customer customer = createUserResult.getTarget();

        PaymentMethodRequest paymentMethodRequest = new PaymentMethodRequest()
                .customerId(customer.getId())
                .paymentMethodNonce("fake-valid-visa-nonce");

        Result<? extends PaymentMethod> createPaymentMethodResult = BT.paymentMethod().create(paymentMethodRequest);

        if(createPaymentMethodResult.isSuccess() == false) {
            System.err.println("Could not create payment method");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if(!(createPaymentMethodResult.getTarget() instanceof CreditCard)) {
            System.err.println("Unexpected error. Result is not a credit card.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        CreditCard creditCard = (CreditCard) createPaymentMethodResult.getTarget();

        SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest = new SubscriptionRequest()
                .paymentMethodToken(creditCard.getToken())
                .planId("mmb2");

        Result<Subscription> createSubscriptionResult = BT.subscription().create(subscriptionRequest);

        if(createSubscriptionResult.isSuccess() == false) {
            System.err.println("Could not create subscription");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Subscription subscription = createSubscriptionResult.getTarget();

        HashMap<String, String> sampleNotification = BT.webhookTesting()
                .sampleNotification(WebhookNotification.Kind.SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY, subscription.getId());

        WebhookNotification webhookNotification = BT.webhookNotification()
                .parse(
                        sampleNotification.get("bt_signature"),
                        sampleNotification.get("bt_payload")
                        );

        System.out.println(webhookNotification.getSubscription().getId());

    }

}
```

but all I'm getting is a `WebhookNotification` instance that has nothing set. Only its ID and the timestamp appears to be set but that's it.

**What I expected:**

I expected to receive a `Subscription` object that tells me which customer has subscribed to it as well as e.g. all add-ons which are included in the billing plan.

Is there a way to get such test-notifications in the sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

`webhookNotification.getSubscription().getId();` will return the ID of the subscription associated with `sampleNotification`, which can be anything for testing purposes, but will be a SubscriptionID in a production environment.

Receiving a dummy object from `webhookTesting().sampleNotification()` is the [expected behavior](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/testing-go-live/java#sample-payload-and-signature), and is in place to help you ensure that all kinds of webhooks can be correctly caught. Once that logic is in place, in the Sandbox Gateway under Settings > Webhooks you can specify your endpoint to receive real webhook notifications.

In the case of `SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGED_SUCCESSFULLY` you will indeed receive a [Subscription object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/java) containing add-on information as well as an array of [Transaction objects](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/java) containing customer information.